# get all users' table values with special row value, firebase web database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have this database:

```
users:                   get(ref(db, `users/${db_uname}/game`)).then((snapshot) => {
  000:                     if (!(snapshot.exists())) {
    game:                    set(ref(db, `users/${db_uname}/game`), {
      cord_x: 0                cord_x: 0,
      cord_y: 0                cord_y: 0
      online: true           });
    password: "000"         }
                            update(ref(db, `users/${db_uname}/game`), {
                              online: true
                            });
                            var con = true;
                            window.db_con = con;
                          });
```

And i need to get `username, game/cord_x, game/cord_y` from all users with game/online == true, to call a function with them later. Please help! :(

```
function getUsers() {
  get(child(db, `users/`)).then((snapshot) => {
      (( DONT KNOW HOW ))
      create_hero(name, x, y);
    })
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the db_uname, cord_x and cord_y for all nodes from your data structure, you can do:

```
get(child(db, `users/`)).then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {                    //  loop over all users
      console.log(userSnapshot.key);                        // "000"
      console.log(userSnapshot.child("game/cord_x").val()); // 0
      console.log(userSnapshot.child("game/cord_y").val()); // 1
    });
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Frank van Puffelen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74901173/17789313) i made what i needed,
if someone ever needs needs it, here it is:

```
function getUsers() {
  get(ref(db, 'users')).then((snap) => {
    snap.forEach((userSnap) => {
      if (userSnap.child("game").exists) {
        if (userSnap.child("game/online").val()) {
          createHero(userSnap.key, userSnap.child("game/cord_x").val(), userSnap.child("game/cord_y").val());
        } else {
          removeHero(userSnap.key);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```